# Google play rejected my app due to login. Http problem

Tags: android, http, https, google-play

My app was rejected by google play. Due to the reason that they cannot login.
They provided me screenshots where they cannot login.
I use http protocol because https protocol temporarily does not work. I have already added to the manifest this lines

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
```

But this doesn't help. Google rejected it anyway. I tested on many devices and everything work fine. Devices on which I cheked:

- Galaxy J3, android 8.0
- Galaxy A7, android 10.0
- SM 520F, android 8.0
- Also in emulator Pixel XL API 30, android 11.0

Has someone encountered such problem?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, my app was also rejected login attempt failed. My login was only working in Pakistan. So I allow for my login even HTTP request has some error so you can make a sample login like demo@gmail.com and allow this to log in to your app in any case and submit your new version of build-in google play.